# How to stop a infinite running process (ztail) started by a ssh session after that session is closed

Tags: command-line, ssh, terminal, process, kill

I have a peculiar problem. My server supports multiple ssh session simultaneously, so that multiple admins can manage (via command line interface) it simultaneously. We have a command which calls `ztail` to show the compressed log files. Now when the current ssh session is closed (without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, to stop the `ztail` command), this command should ideally stop working. But what I observed when I start a new ssh session that, the process (`ztail`) is still running in background and consuming my CPU, even though the previous session was closed. Now how can I know when the session was closed, so that I can use that variable/flag to close/stop any commands initiated by that previously closed session?

Comment: This normally happens automatically, so ztail must be doing something to prevent dying. Programs started in an SSH session receive a SIGHUP when the session terminates. What is this ztail program, and how is it started?

Answer (score 1):

This only happens if you run `ztail` (or any other command) as a new root-level process (i.e. without a parent process), e.g. in the background or via cron.

Usually when you start a standard `ssh` session you get a shell process, which is the root process for all programs you start. If the `ssh` session terminates, the kernel kills all child processes as well. (That's why people usually use `screen` or comparable things to retain sessions.)

So the easiest thing for you would be to utilize this default behavior. Have a look at `ps axjf` to check what `ztail`'s root process is, then figure out why it survives the terminated `ssh` session.

Comment: "If the ssh session terminates, the kernel kills all child processes as well."  Not exactly.  The kernel sends a `SIGHUP` to the process group when the controlling terminal disappears, or the session leader dies creating an orphaned process group.  It is likely ztail is either affecting sessions/process groups with `setpgid` or `setsid`, or ignoring `SIGHUP`.  See [chapter 9 in APUE](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/unix/9780321638014/9dot-process-relationships/ch09) for all the gory details.

Answer (score 0):

During the ssh-session a shell-session will be a child process. That child process will have another child process: `ztail`. After closing the shell ztail will loose its parents. As with all these processes, they will be adoped by init with PID 1.

To if the parent-pid of `ztail`is 1, it is most probably one of your "zombies".